# How to send post request using data from Google Sheets

Tags: python, http, post, request, google-sheets-api

I would like to know what I would need to do to successfully send a post request that grabs this data from google sheets and posts it to the website(lets say "www.fc.com"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSeUT.png)). I have been searching the web but the ones I do see are pretty confusing examples. If anyone can help me out it would be appreciated! Thanks! Here is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("client_secret.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("python google spreadsheets").sheet1

# Add a new Row!
row = ["I", "am", "Kenny", "Whats", "your", "name", "?"]
index=147
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
print(sheet.row_count)
```

Comment: Where is the code supposed to run?

Comment: I am running the code in my terminal with "python spreadsheet.py"

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.